# How to randomize the entries in a List so the user sees a different DailyPrayer each time?

Tags: java, list, collections

I have a method that does a lookup of some elements and returns them to the user:

```
List<DailyPrayer> dailyPrayers = (List<DailyPrayer>) query.execute();
return dailyPrayers;
```

These are daily prayers so I want the user to see a different prayer each time so they do not get bored with seeing the same content in the same order over and over.

How can I randomize the List?

Comment: How about selecting a random item in the database?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Collections.shuffle(list)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29)

> Randomly permutes the specified list using a default source of randomness. All permutations occur with approximately equal likelihood.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Collections.shuffle(dailyPrayers);`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29)

Answer (score 1):

```
shuffle(List<?> list)
          Randomly permutes the specified list using a default source of randomness.
```